# Jquery - How to check, if child in hidden DIV is visible?

Tags: jquery

how can i check a div in a hidden div ...  if visible or not?

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="two_child"></div>
  <div id="three_child" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
if($('#two_child').is(':visible'))
{
  alert('true');
}
```

This will not work.

Any ideas`?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: How can a child in a hidden div be visible?

Comment: I think there's some confusion here, it's *not* visible, since it isn't dislayed....because a parent being hidden means it's hidden as well. `:visible` doesn't mean `display != "none"`, it means *is it visible* (does it have dimensions?), and it's not.

Comment: From the point of view of user of the web page, the child will be invisible, but what status is returned by `is(':visible')`?
Does it return the implicit or explicit visibility?

Comment: All children in an element that has `display:none` will be hidden. But I think that Peter wants to know what it's own display-property is. But I can't think of a reason why you want to know that... The answer of Steve Greatrex should get what you want anyway.

Comment: Visible checks for visibility of the element, not just the `display` style. See my answer on how to filter the selection using `.filter()`, then you can check the style.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could check the `display` property of the css:

```
if ($("#two_child").css("display") != "none") {
    //...
}
```

As Gaby points out in the comments, this would not work if your elements are being hidden using `visibility`, so you may want to extend it to:

```
var $child = $("#two_child");
if ($child.css("display") != "none" && $child.css("visibility") != "hidden") {
    //...
}
```

Comment: @David - He's checking `!= "none"`, *any* other display type would be valid.

Comment: sorry, I meant what if display == '' ?  does jQuery automatically replace '' with none?

Comment: @David - `""` dos display will be the default for the element, for a `<div>` it's `block`, for a `<li>` it's `list-item`, etc.

Comment: it would fail for `visibility:hidden`

Comment: @Gaby - it depends on your definition of "visible", `visibility: hidden` still occupies space in the page, so it is something you can see.

Comment: @nick, i agree that it depends.. but in the same manner, an ancestor `display:none` means all children are invisible (*as jquery supports*). I was only offering an additional case to watch for, since the OP is unclear on what he wants exactly..

Answer (score 6):

I've saved these two selector extensions which is essentially the same as Steve's version:

From [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553534/jquery-detect-visible-but-hidden-elements):

```
// jQuery selector to find if an element is hidden by its parent
jQuery.expr[':'].hiddenByParent = function(a) {
 return $(a).is(':hidden') && $(a).css('display') != 'none' && $(a).css('visibility') == 'visible';
};
```

From Remy Sharp & Paul Irish:

```
// reallyvisible - by remy sharp & paul irish
// :visible doesn't take in to account the parent's visiblity - 'reallyvisible' does...daft name, but does the job.
// not neccessary in 1.3.2+
$.expr[ ":" ].reallyvisible = function(a){ return !(jQuery(a).is(':hidden') || jQuery(a).parents(':hidden').length); };
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector does not work like this

> *Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons*:
>
> - They have a CSS display value of none.
> - They are form elements with
>   type="hidden".
> - Their width and height
>   are explicitly set to 0.
> - ***An ancestor
>   element is hidden, so the element is
>   not shown on the page.***

if you want to check for css properties you can create a custom css selector as displayed in [Select Element By CSS style (all with given style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260210/select-element-by-css-style-all-with-given-style/3260284#3260284)

Comment: It's not `:isvisible`, it's `:visible`

Answer (score 3):

Use filters to check the `display` style, **[an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3bE7/)**

```
$("div")
.filter(function(){
    return $(this).css("display") == "none";
}).find("> div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("display") != "none";
}).length
```

**Reference**

- [jQuery .filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score -1):

Because a child of a hidden element will always be hidden from display, you might try

```
$("#child_two").css("style") == "none"
```

This only works when you hide stuff with css though.

Answer (score -4):

just return false :-) An item in a box you cant find... well... you probably lost that item with the box ;-)

Comment: thanks for telling that on a 3 year old thread. This really made Peters day and now he can finally move on with his quest for finding an element in an hidden element.