# jQuery 2.1.0 | Detect when element visibility is dynamically set to hidden

Tags: jquery, css, hidden

I am having trouble detecting when a button's visibility is dynamically hidden as per `element.css("visibility","hidden")`. I'm using the code below but seems I'm missing something:

```
var invisible = $('#next-button').filter(function() {
return ($(this).parent().css('visibility') == 'inline'
&& ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' || $(this).css('display') == 'none'));
});

setTimeout(function(){if ( invisible ) {
alert('not visible');
}}, 1000);
```

The button's visibility is dynamically hidden after a Youtube API 3 channel search finds the last video of a Youtube channel. The button visibility is hidden to preserve its layout between other `display:inline` visible elements, as opposed to `display:none` which cannot be used in the inline layout. The alert always triggers regardless if the button's visibility is hidden or not. I also tried `if ( invisible == true )` and no alert pops up, and no errors in console. Am I missing something? Thx for pointers.

Comment: According to jQuery specs, "Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout." Maybe the filter method isn't helpful after all?

Comment: Perhaps it's best to read the fine print before downvoting needlessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, a working solution thanks to Barney Scott's answer found in [jQuery detect visible but hidden elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553534/jquery-detect-visible-but-hidden-elements?rq=1) which I've adapted for my needs:

```
$('#button-placeholder:visible').find('#next-button').each(function(){
if ($(this).css('visibility') !== 'visible') {
alert('The visible parent contains an invisible child button that has layout');
}
});
```